# Second stack prints blank using GList

Tags: c++, stack, glib

I'm implementing this data structure (infix to postfix) using stack.

Basically, I'm testing with push and print, no pop operation. The first stack ie., `stack` holds the operator and numbers while the second stack `stack_precedence` records precedence. I think both stacks work fine but I don't understand why precedence stack is not printing the precedence numbers and instead returns blank output.

Partial implementation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <glib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        GList *stack = nullptr;
        GList *stack_precedence = nullptr;

        int size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++) {
                int precedence = 0;
                bool is_precedence_set = false;
                switch (argv[1][i]) {
                /*
                 * Precedence order:
                 * 3) ^
                 * 2) / *
                 * 1) + -
                 * 0) ( )
                 */
                case '^':
                        precedence = 3;
                        is_precedence_set = true;
                case '/':
                case '*':
                        if (!is_precedence_set) {
                                precedence = 2;
                                is_precedence_set = true;
                        }
                case '+':
                case '-':
                        if (!is_precedence_set) {
                                precedence = 1;
                                is_precedence_set = true;
                        }
                case '(':
                        if (!is_precedence_set) {
                                precedence = 0;
                                is_precedence_set = true;
                        }

                        stack = g_list_append(
                                        stack, GINT_TO_POINTER(argv[1][i]));
                        stack_precedence = g_list_append(
                                        stack_precedence, GINT_TO_POINTER(precedence));
                        size++;
                        break;
                case ')':
                        if (!is_precedence_set) {
                                precedence = 0;
                                is_precedence_set = true;
                        }
                        break;
                default:
                        if (argv[1][i] >= '0' and argv[1][i] <= '9') {
                                precedence = 9;
                                stack = g_list_append(
                                                stack, GINT_TO_POINTER(argv[1][i]));
                                stack_precedence = g_list_append(
                                                stack_precedence, GINT_TO_POINTER(precedence));
                                size++;
                        }
                }
        }

        cout << "Stack size: " << size << endl;

        stack = g_list_first(stack);
        while (stack != nullptr) {
                char c = GPOINTER_TO_INT(stack->data);
                cout << c;
                stack = g_list_next(stack);
        }
        cout << endl;

        stack_precedence = g_list_first(stack_precedence);
        while (stack_precedence != nullptr) {
                char c = GPOINTER_TO_INT(stack_precedence->data);
                cout << c;
                stack_precedence = g_list_next(stack_precedence);
        }
        cout << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

I pass in 2+2 as an argument to my program and `stack` works printing 2+2 exactly but `stack_precedence` returns blank.

My expected outcome is

**2+2

919**

And not

**2+2

*blank***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precedences are integers not characters

```
int c = GPOINTER_TO_INT(stack_precedence->data);
^^^ change here
```

Comment: However, I'm a little confused... First stack 2+2 where printing was a success. How was 2 printable? Since it's an int

Comment: @KeyikedalubeNdang No it not, it's a character. You have `char *argv[]` so `argv[1][i]` is a character. But `int precedence = 0;` is clearly an integer. You have to pay attention to types in C++.

Comment: Thanks again @john ;) I had my head banging on my keyboard after two hours of trying to solve this issue yesterday. Now I'm fresh. I need to pay more attention to types.